# How to run streamlit in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, streamlit

I can't run streamlit in my Pycharm.

I didn't find anything to fix this problems.

If i write to terminal streamlit run daily_kpi_follow_up.py , i saw this message. Please, could you tell me how to fix that ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxsbY.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Streamlit isn't installed. You can run `pip install streamlit` in your terminal (PyCharm uses pip by default) or use the [PyCharm UI Wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) and select Streamlit.